# Getting contradictory information regarding the linux distribution

Tags: linux, distributions, version

I wanted to check which linux distribution is running on a remote linux box given to me .i have see [this answer on super user](https://superuser.com/a/11020/173338) which says that

> LSB tools provide this information

And then it goes on to say that on systems where LSB is not installed for most popular distros the following will do the trick :

```
cat /etc/*{release,version}
```

Now here is what I saw using these two techniques :

```
[subhrcho@slc04lyo pcbpel]$ lsb_release -irc
Distributor ID: EnterpriseEnterpriseServer
Release:        5.8
Codename:       Carthage
[subhrcho@slc04lyo pcbpel]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)
```

My question why am I getting contradictory information from running these commands ? What am I missing here ?

Additional information  : When issuing uname -or command I get the following :

```
2.6.18-308.4.1.0.1.el5xen GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not contradictory information. What you're running is Oracle Enterprise Linux, based on RHEL. For more info, [check here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10505767) .

Comment: Whats the deal with these two code names "Carthage" and "Tikanga"..why are they different ?

Comment: Carthage is the codename for Oracle's distribution, based on Redhat's, which is codenamed Tikanga.